# AWS SES createTemplate in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to know how create a template (html) using the SES's Api.  I checked the docs but I don't understand much: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html

Right now, I know how to send emails using SES, but I need to know how to use templates.

Is there an easy way to use CURL and create the template like I did to send the emails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create **email template** in AWS SES
**Follow the below steps :-**

- Login to AWS and the goto AWS SES service and enable the service and
  verify your emails in Verified identities    Download the PHP SDK for
  AWS in zip and extract it to your project    file.
- Get the AWS access key and secrete for your account details    (This
  global access key for all services not only for SES) Create a    text
  file .aws/credential.txt and add above keys details like below

> [default]
> aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
> aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

- Now to setup the credential path, go to `AWSSDK/Aws/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php` line no. 766    `getHomeDir()` and return the base path of your project to
  access   `.aws/credential.txt`
  **OR**
  you can refere to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html
  doc for setting up the credentials for AWS SES.
- Now use this doc  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/ses-template.html
  for reference to create, delete and send email template in AWS SES with php.